# ArchLinux LxQt Weird characters everywhere

Tags: qt, locale, archlinux

I've just installed Arch and LxQt, when I lookup things on the ArchWiki it shows weird characters (black/white circles, squares...) at the place where the quoted texts are. I did uncomment "en_US.UTF-8" and "zh_TW.UTF-8" and ran localegen.

Any pointer ? I am an Arch beginner.

Regards,
Jonathan MONDAUT

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have `ttf-dejavu` installed in your computer. If not, you can install it with the following command.

```
pacman -S ttf-dejavu
```

You can check with the following in your Terminal.

```
if (pacman -Q ttf-dejavu >/dev/null) ; then echo "ttf-dejavu installed"; fi
```